# Free iOS App with Video Playlist, folders & iTunes USB file share support?

Tags: video, ios, media-player, itunes

Free iOS App with Video Playlist, folders & iTunes USB file share support?

- Video Playists; inbuilt and/ or m3u/ xspf support
- Local Folders & Sub folders for organizing files/ data/ media
- iTunes File/ Folder share - Drag & Drop via iTunes

PS: If you name VLC, I know about it and use it on Windows, but it does not have Playlist & Folder support on iOS.